# How to display timecreated in a dateformat?

Tags: javascript, steam

I'm trying to display the timecreated in a date format using javascript but I can't seem to find any documentation about it online...
If anyone knows how to do that would help a lot!

Comment: What "timecreated" are you talking about?

Comment: From GetPlayerSummaries, the one that displays when the account was created. Currently it only displays a long set of numbers

Comment: A set of long numbers is probably a Unix timestamp? https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If timecreated is a Unix timestamp, you can use

```
var date = new Date(timecreated * 1000);
```

because a unix timestamp is the number of seconds since 1970. If not, it might be enough to just put `new Date(timecreated)`